# i have this error: argument of type 'char' is incompatible with parameter of type char*

Tags: c, pointers, char

My program is supposed to convert all characters in lowercase except the one that are at the beginning of the word. For example bla bla bla should become Bla Bla.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TRUE -1
#define FALSE 0
void incaps1(char*s)
{int i;
 int PreviousCharWasSpace;

    for(i=0,PreviousCharWasSpace=TRUE ; i!=sizeof(*s) ; i++)
    {   if (*(s+i)==' ')
            PreviousCharWasSpace=TRUE;
        else{
            if (PreviousCharWasSpace)
            {   *(s+i)=toupper(*(s+i));
                PreviousCharWasSpace=FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",*s);
}



 int main(){
     char phrase[256];
     while(gets(phrase)){
         char*s=phrase;
         incaps1(*s);
      }
```

I have an error in incpas1(*s) which underlines '*' and says "error:argument of type 'char' is incompatible with parameter of type char*  "
    }

Comment: Please explain in a few sentences what your program should do and if possible an example of your input and expected output. That way nobody needs to go through your code and try to understand what it should do, before focusing on the error.

Comment: My program is supposed to convert all characters in lowercase except the one that are at the beginning of the word. For example bla bla bla should become Bla Bla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean

```
incaps1( s );
        ^^^^
```

Take into account that this loop is wrong

```
for(i=0,PreviousCharWasSpace=TRUE ; i!=sizeof(*s) ; i++)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It seems there must be at least

```
for(i=0,PreviousCharWasSpace=TRUE ; i!=strlen(s) ; i++)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here is also a mistake

```
printf("%s\n",*s);
```

Write instead

```
printf("%s\n", s);
              ^^^
```

Comment: if i use incaps1( s ); then i will have en error.

Unhandled exception at 0x5456ED6C (msvcr110d.dll) in Coursework.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000042.

Comment: @AlexandrosTsos I do not see such a function name in you code. Maybe your project has other files.

Comment: i see that I made a mistake there and i thank you for pointing out. The program compiles now, it executes. I type bla bla for example and when i hit enter I have this. Unhandled exception at 0x5441ED6C (msvcr110d.dll) in Coursework.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000042.

Comment: @AlexandrosTsos `printf("%s\n", *s);` may be causing the error, instead use `printf("%s\n", s);`.

Comment: You are a small god SIR. I SALUTE YOU.